# Filter collection with millis data on MODIS

Tags: modis, image

I'm trying to split a modis collection in two others, using like a splitter a data time that's defined in millis. I don't want to do it manually.

```
var maskMOD13Q1 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('SummaryQA');
  var mask0 = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 0).eq(0);
  var mask1 = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 1).eq(0);

  var mask = mask0.and(mask1)

  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var point = geometry

var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
.filterBounds(point)
.map(maskMOD13Q1)



print(col)

Map.setOptions('satellite')
var chart1 = ui.Chart.image.series(col.select('NDVI'), geometry, ee.Reducer.first(), 10)
  .setOptions({title: 'titleGraph', 
               lineWidth: 0,
               pointSize: 2})

//print(chart1)

var chart1 = ui.Chart.image.series(col.select('NDVI'), geometry2, ee.Reducer.first(), 10)
  .setOptions({title: 'titleGraph', 
               lineWidth: 0,
               pointSize: 2})

//print(chart1)

var chart1 = ui.Chart.image.series(col.select('NDVI'), geometry3, ee.Reducer.first(), 10)
  .setOptions({title: 'titleGraph', 
               lineWidth: 0,
               pointSize: 2})
//print(chart1)

var im1 = ee.Image(ba.select('BurnDate').toList(1000).get(156))
print(im1)
Map.addLayer(im1,{min:0,max:1},'im1',true)

var im2 = ee.Image(ba.select('BurnDate').toList(1000).get(224))
print(im2)
Map.addLayer(im2,{min:0,max:1},'im2',true)

Map.addLayer(ba.reduce(ee.Reducer.count()),{min:0,max:1},'count',true)

print(ba)

var colbd1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
.filter.('system:time_start','1570043461095894')
.filterBounds(point)
.map(maskMOD13Q1,'try')

print(colbd1)
```

but I get this error:

> Received too many arguments to function filter(). Expected at most 1
>   but got 2.